# How to use an Amazon affiliate link?

Tags: amazon

There's someone online I want to support by using their Amazon (.co.uk) affiliate link for my online purchases. Seems like a win-win. But I'm a bit confused about how to use it.

The link contains a `?tag=abc1234` query parameter, but after I navigate away from the main page, that parameter is lost from the URL. I can't find a setting in my Amazon preferences to put that tag permanently. And nowhere in the process of making a purchase do I see any indication that I'm supporting any Amazon affiliate.

So how does the affiliate link work? How do I make sure I'm using it correctly?

Google has been particularly unhelpful in answering this question. I only get search results on how to *be* an Amazon associate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enter Amazon using the link with that tag - and make sure you have cookies enabled on your computer.    Amazon do the rest, by placing a cookie on your machine when you use a link that includes the tag.

It will be active for a certain amount of time since you last used it, and (I suspect) unless you use someone else's affiliate link in the meantime.    However I do not know what that length of time is    (It may have been 30 days in the past, but I'm not sure if that is current.)

Comment: So since I've used the affiliate link once, will it now be active any time I go to Amazon the normal way? Or does it have to be the same session? Is there a time-limit? Is there any place on the Amazon website where I can see if the tag is active?

Comment: I've expanded the answer for you.